# Usage of User32.dll ToUnicodeEx function

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi

On a system with a non-US keyboard / culture, I am receiving a Barcode from a scanner as keyboard input. The scanner can be set to different cultures. In my case it is set to en-US. In this case the system language and the barcode scanner language encoding are different.

I have declared this function to decode:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern int ToUnicodeEx(uint virtualKeyCode, uint scanCode, byte[] keyboardState, [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr, SizeParamIndex = 4)] StringBuilder receivingBuffer, int bufferSize, uint flags, IntPtr dwhkl);
```

I use the method below to load a keyboard layout:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr LoadKeyboardLayout(string pwszKLID, uint Flags);
```

I use the method like below:

```
// loads the interpretation of the key into buf.
ToUnicodeEx(key, scankey, keyboardState, buf, 256, 0, LoadKeyboardLayout("00000409", 1));
```

My usage of the method works - the interpretation is correct - BUT I have a side effect that my system language setting is affected. Before method call it looks like this:

[image]

And after the method call it looks like this:

[image]

**How can I fix my code so that my system's language is not affected?**

I have tried to change flags parameter of the LoadKeyboardLayout to 0, but then ToUnicodeEx uses the system language, not the loaded en-US.

Comment: Documented [here for `LoadKeyboardLayout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646305.aspx): "Beginning in Windows 8: The input locale identifier is loaded for the entire system." The obvious workaround is to unload the keyboard layout. Or use a different translation system that doesn't require global changes to system state. `ToUnicodeEx` is undesirable anyway because it changes the state of the system keyboard buffer.

Comment: I suppose you discovered why the barcode scanner manufacturer decided that it was a good idea to make it localizable by itself.  Live and learn.

Comment: @HansPassant I it is true that the scanner is localizable, but only to the major languages like e.g. English, Spanish, German and so on. Smaller languages like in my case Danish, is not an option.

Comment: @CodyGray I read this documentation. Are there any possible way to work around it? As stated I imagined that I could load the layout, not "activate" it, and then I could do the interpretation in background... But without activation, it doesn't work. Then you could ask if ToUnicodeEx always uses the system langauge, how does it differ from the ToUnicode method? I thought it would be exactly to allow a different keyboard than the system.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure that almost four years later you've either solved this or no longer care. I'll put the answer here in case someone else comes across this, though.

The last parameter of `LoadKeyboardLayout` is `dwFlags`. You gave it `1`, which is equivalent to `KLF_ACTIVATE`, or "load this bad boy up and make it my keyboard!"

You want to call it with `0`, which tells it to just load the layout, give you a handle (IntPtr) to it, and do nothing else.

I'm sorry I couldn't help you back when you posted this. :-)